# Accesing oneToMany data from odoo model (odoo 12)

Tags: odoo, odoo-12

I have a list of tasks related to a project in a one-to-many relationship one project have many tasks, reading the [official documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/reference/orm.html#field-access) the field access should be as easy as iterating on a list and access the field by name, this is the code I have done so far:

```
def _roles_assigned(self):
    for rec in self:
        total = len(rec.task_ids)
        for e in rec.tasks
            logging.info(e.status) #<-- this should print status
```

I print the result and get 'project.task(X,)' where I guess X is the Id of the task, how can I access the task properties?

Note: the field is a selection field

Comment: Yes x is the id and projet.task is the table name and you can access all fields by using e.fiels_name like you already did with status. Try printing e.name

Comment: I just get True or False which is not the type of the property it's a selection

Comment: That is un-usual are you sure you are using print(e.status) and also try in log info e._status

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the field is a selection I had to access the dictionary

```
@api.multi
@api.depends('task_ids')
def _roles_assigned(self):
    for rec in self:
        total = len(rec.tasks)
        assigned = 0
        for e in rec.tasks:
            selected = dict(e._fields['status'].selection).get(e.status) #<-- getting selected value from a selection field
```

Answer (score 1):

try something like this:

```
def _roles_assigned(self):
    for tasks in self.task_ids:
        logging.info(tasks.status)
```